# Compiling cocos2d-x sample LiquidFun-Testbed Xcode 10.2 - Missing files on compile-time

Tags: cocos2d-x, xcode10.2

**Disclaimer: I have posted the same issue over at https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-samples/issues. I realise that cross-posting is usually not encouraged. However, after having a closer look at mentioned issues page on posted GitHub page, it seems to me that that page is highly inactive, and posting here has a far higher chance of valid and useful input.**

I've been trying to build the cocos2d-x samples by following the steps from https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-samples exactly, namely

> **Download**
>
> $ git clone https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-samples.git
>
> $ cd cocos2d-x-samples $ python download-engine.py
>
> **Running**
>
> Once the samples were downloaded just go any sample, and open the
>   project. eg:
>
> $ cd cocos2d-x-samples/samples/LiquidFun-Testbed/proj.ios_mac
>
> $ open LiquidFun-Testbed.xcodeproj/

However, when I build the LiquidFun-Testbed.xcodeproj, while targeting iOS, I get

```
Showing All Errors Only

Prepare build
note: Using legacy build system


Build target libcocos2d iOS of project cocos2d_libs with configuration Debug


Build target LiquidFun-Testbed iOS of project LiquidFun-Testbed with configuration Debug

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/liquidfun/liquidfun/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2EdgeAndPolygonContact.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/liquidfun/liquidfun/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/b2Distance.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/liquidfun/liquidfun/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/Common/b2StackAllocator.cpp'
clang: error: no input files



Build failed    06.01.20, 22:25    698.2 seconds
```

It looks like the compiler is looking for files in

```
/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/liquidfun/liquidfun/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/
```

but this path was never created.

After following the mentioned steps above, Box2D and its code are instead placed in

```
/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/cocos2d-x/external/Box2D
```

...So I am wondering

**A) Why is it looking for these files in**

`/Users/Chris/Desktop/source/repos/3rd party libraries/cocos2d-x-samples/libs/liquidfun/liquidfun/liquidfun/Box2D/Box2D/`?

**B) What can I do to fix this and get these samples to build?**